# Issue using rows and columns

Tags: html, row, col

I am trying to add a row and several columns to my layout. When I apply the row and column classes nothing appears to change.

I'm not sure if I added Bootstrap to my file incorrectly or what could be causing this. Any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="bgimage">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Headline</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class= col-md-2>
                    <h1>Headline</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class= col-md-2>
                    <h1>Headline</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class= col-md-2>
                    <h1>Headline</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing quotes around the classes being defined. `<div class = col-md-2>` should be `<div class="col-md-2">`.  You should also include your code instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things here that could be causing you some issues.

The reference link to the css files like `bootstrap.min.css` should have the media type defined like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

You're also missing quotes `"` around the classes being added to the column `div` elements.

```
<div class = col-md-2>
```

Should be changed to:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
```

Leaving you with

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <h1>Headline</h1>
        <p>
            lorem ispum...
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```